# display more DAGs and more days in airflow?

Tags: airflow, dashboard

We use airflow for some big jobs and a few smaller ones. We have a large number of small-ish jobs we would like to set up as DAGs, but how can one see more of the success/failure results as they are running? The thought of looking at the web interface just makes me feel tired. I would have to be hitting a "Next" button hundreds of times.

Here is just a bit from an app I created. But I do not want to have to extend this app. Why should I be re-inventing this wheel here?

The table below has more than a 1000 rows and can have up to 3000+ and I can look at over 90 days of data because... well, why should I not?

So how can I get this sort of display out of airflow? Or is there something 3rd-party that uses airflow and will do this?

See: [image: part of a page]

Comment: Apparently, it is not possible to get more information displayed in the UI, but one can query the API to get the data and put up an application that displays more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no answer. It is no other UIs available that show more DAGs.